# How do i make the output come in different columns?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, multiple-columns

Im making a program that outputs, the numbers 1-10 in one column, the square of this in another and in the third the number in cube.

How can i make the program a little nicer so the columns really differ.
And for every column i like to add a Title(Number, number squared, number cube).

//Sorry for my bad English

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Del2upp3 extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    int i;
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Press");
    Del2upp3()
    {
        super ("Panel"); setSize (200,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container con = this.getContentPane();
        con.add(panel);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(button);
        setVisible(true);

    } 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {        
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source == button)  
        {

            StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
                for( i = 1; i< 11; i++){

                string.append("\n     ").append(i);
                string.append(", ").append(i*i);
                string.append(", ").append(i*i*i);

        }
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string,"Data",
               JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
               setSize (200,200);
               setVisible(true); 
                 i = 0;
         }}
        public static void main(String[] args){new Del2upp3();} 
   }
```

Comment: For a Swing GUI, it would be best to display the results in a JTable. You could put the results in a 2D Integer array and then use that array as part of your JTable's model.

Comment: yes - the JTable is a more proper GUI structure - not sure if OP is ready for more Swing or just looking to print some simple stuff..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting a `String` using HTML is an excellent and often overlooked idea (+1 to Maroun)

Something else that often gets over looked is the ability for `JOptionPane` to use `JComponent`s

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableOptionPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableOptionPane();
    }

    public TableOptionPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                Integer[][] values = new Integer[10][3];
                StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                    values[i - 1][0] = i;
                    values[i - 1][1] = i * i;
                    values[i - 1][2] = i * i * i;
                }
                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(values, new Object[]{"i", "i * i", "i * i * i"});
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table), "Data", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The has the added benifit of providing a bases from which you could support such operations as "copy" or even edibility of the data, if such things were of use to you...

You may find more details at [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Nice and detailed answer! +1

Comment: Great answer!
BUt what does "Integer[10][3]" the numbers stand for?

Comment: It allocates a 2 dimensional Integer array of 10 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: So if i want different set of rows and columns, i change the values?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for details

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) in your case.

But you can use [HTML Tags](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/) and do something like this:

```
builder.append("<html><table border=1><tr><td>column1</td><td>column2</td><td></tr>");
string.append("<tr><td>");
string.append(.....);
string.append("</td><td>");
...
string.append("</td></tr>");
string.append("</table></html>");
```

<strike>Or:</strike>

```
textArea.setText("column1\t\tcolumn2\n");  
textArea.append("column1\t\tcolumn2\n");  
textArea.append(...);
```

But it's not recommended since your text can go out of the column.