# how to make a pop-up window using java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist

I wanted a button to show a pop-up window, I tried using the

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
```

But I can't put my desired object such as the Table and List. Is it possible?

Comment: `JOptionPane` + [`JTable` example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6175860/418556) & [`JList` example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13718134/418556).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really poorly documented in the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), because all that tells you is that the "message" parameter is an Object, which can be anything - but does not go into specifics about what happens with different types of objects that may warrant special case handling.

As far as I have gathered from experimenting with it, the "message" can be a subtype of Component - then it will just place the component in the message area of the dialog box as-is, like:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JCheckBox("I'm a checkbox!"));
```

Otherwise, it will just call the toString method on the object, converting it into a string, which it then will just wrap in a label and place that in the dialog as the message.

But you can also pass in an *Array* of Objects, in which case it will just place each element in a separate row in the message area:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Object[] {
    new JCheckBox("check"),
    new JRadioButton("radio"),
    "plain text"});
```

There might be other special cases, but I haven't found them yet.

That said, if what you want to display is a subclass of Component (or JComponent), just passing it in as the message parameter should work. If it doesn't, you might want to edit your question to describe whatever problems you are encountering in more detail, perhaps also providing some sample code.

Comment: I didn't know about that array behavior. Good call! :-D

Comment: @peeskillet: And that's why the documentation for JOptionPane is really, *really* poor, if you can only discover such features by trial-and-error...

Comment: I always just threw a panel (with components) in there ;-)

Comment: @AndreasBaus wow, it really helped a lot, thanks for taking your time answering my question :D

Comment: @peeskillet: ... and you will still have to do that if you want to have any control over the layout of the components :)

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a closer look at the [`JOptionPane` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), [`showMessageDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) clearly states that it accepts a `Object` as the message parameter

One of the nice features of this, is if the `Object` is `Component`, it will be added to the dialog.

For example: [JOptionPane displaying HTML problems in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702689/joptionpane-displaying-html-problems-in-java/12702858#12702858) and [How do i make the output come in different columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450293/how-do-i-make-the-output-come-in-different-columns/16450826#16450826)